# Too many/ Too little faces and vertices in Edit mode

Tags: sculpting, faces, subdivision-surface

[image: This dark ands with hundreds of faces only in a few areas showed up after I sculpted and the area around where I sculpted is blank.]

Why did this happen and can I fix it? This happens every time I sculpt with this model and I don't know what to do or what's happening. No one else seems to have had this problem as I've described it because no results show in Google. Sculpting was hard enough since it seemed like the model would randomly start to rise out of itself while sculpting.

I have already:

- Set the scale (still didn't fix the phantom bubbling, but did fix the brush being oval)
- Reset the normals (nothing happened)
- Subdivide (Still, my curves are jagged) modifier and no modifier
- Unsubdivided (modifier and no modifier)

None of this helped and I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm a beginner.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove your *Mirror* modifier, it's not convenient to sculpt with this modifier, plus your object is already symmetrical so you have overlapping faces. Once removed, symmetrize your mesh (make sure that you've selected the good *Direction*):

[image]

And activate the symmetry option to keep sculpting symmetrically:

[image]

Also the normals of the head are inverted, it inverts the effect of the brushes. Select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate:

[image]

Comment: Omagosh thankyou! Do you know how it got inside out though?

Comment: Do you mean how the normals got inverted? Not sure why... maybe you've mirrored in Edit mode with a SX-1?